# Type Casting of Pointers to Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I have the following elements.

`p1`: A pointer to the class union.

`r1` A pointer inside the class union which points to a Region Class.

`A.x` A point inside the class Rectangle.

Union and Rectangle are derived classes from the base class Region.

I'm doing the following operation.

```
auto p1 = new Union();
p1->r1 = new Rectangle();
```

Now I want to change a point inside r1.

How can I typecast a pointer inside a pointer, For example I tried this and it doesn't work.

`p1->(Rectangle*)r1->B.x = 6;`

However this works perfectly,

```
auto r11 = (Rectangle*)p1->r1;
r11->A.x = 1;
```

How can I change `p1->(Rectangle*)r1->B.x = 6;` to directly change A.x without creating a new pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check out operator precedence and it's associativity.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

The correct form is:

```
((Rectangle*)p1->r1)->B.x = 6;
```

To be more precise, this is how it works:

1. Access Rectangle * member r1 with -> (left-to-right)
2. Cast it to Rectangle * (right-to-left)
3. Access B member (left-to-right). Take into account that -> has higher precedence than casting `(Rectangle*)`, this is why we have parentheses in `((Rectangle*)p1->r1)`.
4. Access x member through . operator